# Should I use an std::vector or a std::unique_ptr here?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, smart-pointers

I have a `Mesh` class that I want to have ownership over several different "array-like" structures for `vertices`,`indices`,`vertex_normals`,etc.

I would like for the `Mesh` class to be totally independent of the source of these formats, as I have many 3d formats I need to support.  As such I currently have a set of loader functions that read the 3d data from a specific format, create a mesh, and assign it to an instance of a `Model` (which contains a `unique_ptr` to a specific `Mesh`).

I'm currently doing this by simply heap allocating arrays inside the loader function, then passing the pointers to those arrays into the `Mesh` constructor.  But it seems like using either `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` would be a safer option.  A quick mockup of what one of the loader functions (specifically one meant to load from an OBJ file) might look like is as follows:

```
void load_OBJ(std::shared_ptr<Model> model, std::string file_path){
    # Read the 3d data
    ...

    # Create the Mesh object
    std::unique_ptr<Mesh> mesh(new Mesh());

    # Add the 3d data to the Mesh (???)
    mesh->set_vertices( ??? );
    mesh->set_indices( ??? );
    ...

    # Assign the Mesh object to the Model:
    model->set_mesh(mesh);
};
```

My first gut reaction was, because the `Mesh` will maintain exclusive ownership over all of its members, that I should use `std::unique_ptr`, so something like this:

```
class Mesh {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<Vector3[]> vertices;
        uint32_t num_vertices;

        Mesh() { };
        ~Mesh() { };

        void set_vertices(std::unique_ptr<Vector3[]>& new_vertices, uint32_t num_vertices){
            this->vertices = std::move(new_vertices);
            this->num_vertices = num_vertices;
        };
```

But then I started to wonder if perhaps `std::vector` is a better way to go.  In this context, the speed of being able to access the data from `Mesh` is going to be extremely important.  My rough benchmarks (with compiler optimizations) hint to me though that accessing data from either `std::unique_ptr<Vector3[]>` and `std::vector<Vector3>` are virtually indistinguishable.  So I'm not sure if there is anything else to take into consideration here that I am missing?

Comment: IMHO `std::vector<Vector3>` is a perfect fit.

Comment: @wohlstad i suppose my main concern is that a duplicate of `std::vector` is made when passing it into `mesh->set_vertices()`, whereas with `std::unique_ptr` I can ensure that only one copy ever exists of the vertex data, and ownership over it is restricted solely to the parent `Mesh` object.  But perhaps that isn't a well founded concern.

Comment: Duplicate doesn't have to be made. I'm thinking something like `void set_vertices(std::vector<Vector3>&& new_vertices)` If you're thinking in a different direction, show what you've tried in the question.

Comment: There is to much trouble with `std::unique_ptr<x[]>`. There is no size information (you have to maintain it), there is no implicit copy (only move). It is not iterator friendly. It is hard to resize (add remove items). Only gain is that pointer size will be 8 bytes and `std::vector` size is 24 bytes (internally it is 3 pointers).

Comment: Accessing the data in a `std::unique_ptr<Vector3[]>` or a `std::vector<Vector3>` _should_ be indistinguishable. The `vector` takes up a little more space though (`capacity`).  You don't have to worry about copying if you make it `void set_vertices(std::vector<Vector3>&& new_vertices) { vertices = std::move(new_vertices); }`

Comment: You can use move-semantics to avoid copy of the `std::vector`. And `std::unique_ptr` requires single ownership anyway, which is why you also had to use `std::move`.

Comment: Ahh I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me to use `std::move` on the vector.  That really makes this a clear win for `std::vector`.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::vector` gives you exclusive ownership over a dynamically sized array of elements, which is *exactly* what you want to do. It simplifies things as well by allowing you to save on the error-prone explicit size variable. I'd say go for it.

Using a vector won't introduce much overhead either: It's just a pointer to some memory with an added `size` and `capacity`. (In practice, these are also implemented as pointers, so a vector is just three pointers.)

Make sure to call `reserve` with the appropriate size first if you're going to `push_back` into the vector:

```
vertices.reserve(numVertices);
for (size_t i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
    // load vertex
    vertices.push_back(vertex);
}
```

Otherwise, the vector's default growth policy might make it bigger than you need it to be, wasting memory. (If I recall correctly, a vector doubles in size by default whenever its allocated storage becomes full.)

If you want to `memcpy` into the vector, you have to `resize` it first to allocate an appropriate amount of storage.

To pass the vector around without making copies, use `std::move`. It'll boil down to the same operations as your `unique_ptr` - just shuffling a couple of pointers around. You *can* copy the vector easily when you want to, but you don't have to.

If you want to make a function or constructor that "consumes" a vector (takes ownership of it), just take it by value and move it to its final destination:

```
void Model::setMesh(std::vector<Vertex> vertices) {
    m_mesh = std::move(vertices);
}

std::vector<Vertex> v = ...;
model->setMesh(std::move(v));
```

No copy is ever made there if you call the function with a temporary (or moved object). If you call it with an lvalue, though, it'll make a copy and leave the original object intact. This means that you can choose whether to copy or move something into the function.